# reading JSON response as string using jersey client

Tags: json, string, jersey, response

I am using jersey client to post a file to a REST URI that returns the response as JSON.
My requirement is to read the response as (JSON) to a string.

Here is the piece of code that posts the data to the web service.

```
final ClientResponse clientResp = resource.type(
            MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).
            accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
            post(ClientResponse.class, inputData);
     System.out.println("Response from news Rest Resource : " + clientResp.getEntity(String.class)); // This doesnt work.Displays nothing.
```

`clientResp.getLength()` has 281 bytes which is the size of the response, but `clientResp.getEntity(String.class)` returns nothing.

Any ideas what could be incorrect here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to find solution to the problem. Just had to call bufferEntity method before getEntity(String.class). This will return response as string.

```
   clientResp.bufferEntity();
   String x = clientResp.getEntity(String.class);
```

Comment: At this time the correct Jersey method is readEntity(String.class), instead of getEntity(String.class).

Answer (score 11):

Although the above answer is correct, using Jersey API v2.7 it is slightly different with `Response`:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080");
Response response = target.path("api").path("server").path("ping").request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).get();
System.out.println("Response: " + response.getStatus() + " - " + response.readEntity(String.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still got problem with this, you may want to consider to use [rest-assured](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/)

Comment: Thanks for the respnse. REST-assured seems to be promising, but i can only use jersey client in my project. :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using Jersey 1.19 and Genson got in my classpath somehow? So the accepted answer throws `com.owlike.genson.stream.JsonStreamException: Readen value can not be converted to String`.

My solution was to read directly from the response stream:

```
private String responseString(com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse response) {
        InputStream stream = response.getEntityInputStream();
        StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())))) {
            int c = 0;
            while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
                textBuilder.append((char) c);
            }
            return textBuilder.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```