# clientResponse.getEntity(String.class) returns HTML instead of JSON

Tags: java, json, jersey

I'm trying to fetch an object of `PreRegisterJsonResponse` through web service with jersey client by sending `preRegisterId` as path variable to the service, tested it on Advanced REST client and Postman - it works but when I consume web service through jersey client from java code I get HTML returned instead of JSON.

Here's the code

WebService -

```
@GET
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/userJSON2/{preRegisterId}")
public PreRegisterJsonResponse userJson2(@PathVariable long preRegisterId){
    PreRegisterJsonResponse pjr = new PreRegisterJsonResponse();
    try{
        PreRegister preRegUser = preRegisterDao.get(preRegisterId);
        pjr.setFirstName(preRegUser.getFirstName());
        pjr.setMiddleName(preRegUser.getMiddleName());
        pjr.setLastName(preRegUser.getLastName());
        pjr.setLoginId(preRegUser.getLoginId());
        pjr.setRoleId(preRegUser.getRole().getId());
        pjr.setUrlCode(preRegUser.getUrlCode());
        pjr.setCreatedBy(preRegUser.getCreatedBy().toString());
        if(preRegUser.getInvitedUnder() != null){
            pjr.setInvitedUnderId(preRegUser.getInvitedUnder().getId());
        }else{
            pjr.setInvitedUnderId(0);
        }
        pjr.setSkipBiometrics(preRegUser.isSkipBiometrics());
        pjr.setMainRecordOfficer(preRegUser.getMainRecordOfficer());
        pjr.setEmployeeId(preRegUser.getEmployeeId());
        if(preRegUser.getFond() != null){
            pjr.setFondId(preRegUser.getFond().getId());
        }else{
            pjr.setFondId(0);
        } 
    } catch(Exception ex){
        logger.error("Exception in WebServiceController:userJson2() "+ex.getMessage());
    }

    return pjr;
}
```

Jersey Client -

```
    public static void getInvitedUser(){
    try{
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/webApplication/rest/UserJSON2/"+preRegisterId);
        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
           throw new Exception("Exception in getInvitedUser() : "+ response.getStatus());
        }

        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        System.out.println(output);
        preRegisterUser = gson.fromJson(output, PreRegister.class);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

After consuming web service through Postman and ARC-

```
{
"firstName": "fname",
"middleName": null,
"lastName": "lname",
"loginId": "mith11395@gmail.com",
"roleId": 4,
"urlCode": "1c5f8f37dfb1483db1d694d82fbdcae5",
"createdBy": "50",
"invitedUnderId": 0,
"skipBiometrics": true,
"mainRecordOfficer": null,
"employeeId": "777777",
"fondId": 0
}
```

After consuming web service through jersey client as shown above I get HTML content instead of JSON -

```
Output from Server .... 
<HTML content .......>
```

And then I get this exception -

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

I know the cause for this, it can not convert JSON to object because we haven't received JSON response altogrther(That is the actual problem).
Also I don't get anything in error logs.
What could be the reason, am I missing something ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In jersey if you want to return JSON you should declare it using [`@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/gipxf/index.html)

> The @Produces annotation is used to specify the MIME media types or representations a resource can produce and send back to the client.

In your method add line:

```
@RequestMapping("/userJSON2/{preRegisterId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public PreRegisterJsonResponse userJson2(@PathVariable long preRegisterId) {
```

Comment: Thank you but I have tested with your suggestion but still I get the HTML response

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557404/reading-json-response-as-string-using-jersey-client